# WPF MediaElement with image as Source

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mediaelement

The WPF `MediaElement` displays both videos and **images**. This seems nice, because I want to show a playlist containing both videos and images.

In the `MediaEnded` event handler, I change the source, which then triggers the playback of the next video.

```
<MediaElement Name="Player" Source="{Binding MediaSource}"  MediaEnded="Player_MediaEnded" />

private void Player_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MediaSource = "the_next_file.jpg";
}
```

**But...** When setting the `Source` to an image file, this image is always displayed for **5 seconds**.

#### Question

I want to define the number of seconds that image is visible. But there does not seem to be a way to do that.

Whatever I do... images are always displayed for **5 seconds**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the [MediaClock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.clock?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#system-windows-controls-mediaelement-clock) when an image is the source so that you can control how long it's displayed?

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.clock?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#system-windows-controls-mediaelement-clock

Comment: Isn't that a XAML element for the animation storyboard? Anyway, do you have an example of how to wire up the `MediaClock`? Because I can't seem to get my head around this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a timer to change the `Source` after a specified period of time, e.g.:

```
private async void Player_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Player.MediaEnded -= Player_MediaEnded;

    MediaSource = "pic1.jpg";
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    MediaSource = "pic2.jpg";
}
```